# Center div content horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to center the content of a div in the vertically in the middle, and tried different examples mentioned in previous articles.

My DIV looks like this:

[image]

The content should be in the middle.

I have the follwing HTML

```
<div id="tailoringCategory">
    <div id="centerContent">
        <img id="btnMenu" src="/Images/menu.png" >
        Tailoring Groups:
        <select id="cbTailoringGroups"></select>
        <img id="btnFilter" src="/Images/filter2.jpg" >
    </div>
</div>
```

And the follwing stylesheets:

```
        #tailoringCategory {
            position: absolute;
            top: 20px;
            left: 20px;
            /* width: 635px; */
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            font-family: 'Arial';
            padding: 4px;
            background: #FFFFFF;
            border: 1px solid;
            border-radius: 10px;
            z-index: 1;
            overflow: hidden;
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        #centerContent {
            display: table-cell;
            width:100%;
            height: 100%;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
```

I cannot get it to work

Can s.o. tell me how to do this? The DIV content is hidden and will be expanded by mouseclick

```
                var expandedTailoring = false;
                $("#btnMenu").click(function () {
                    if (expandedTailoring)
                    {
                        $("#tailoringCategory").animate({ width: "30" });
                        expandedTailoring = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#tailoringCategory").animate({ width: "670" });
                        expandedTailoring = true;
                    }

                });
```

When i add display: table to the parent div i get the following even i haven't the div expandet:

[image]

This is with the following CSS:

```
        #tailoringCategory {
            position: absolute;
            top: 20px;
            left: 20px;
            /* width: 635px; */
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            font-family: 'Arial';
            padding: 4px;
            background: #FFFFFF;
            border: 1px solid;
            border-radius: 10px;
            z-index: 1;
            overflow: hidden;
            display: table;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        #centerContent {
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
```

At the beginning only the Menu Icon should be shown (width 30px collapsed div) - and without using table it is.

Comment: #tailoringCategory { display: table; width: 100% };  #centerContent { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; } try this

Comment: Hi Code Lover, the Problem is, that the DIV is not collapsed when i add display: table . All elements are ordered vertically but i want them to be in the middle of the div

Comment: Can you include a screenshot?

Comment: Okay i have. My problem is that the width 30px for the collapsed div is not working when i add css display:table to the parent container.

Comment: Your screenshot does not work.

Comment: Try doing this: <div id="outer-container" class="full-width full-height"><div class="table"><div class="table-cell"><div id="YOUR_COLLAPSE_DIV_CONTAINER" style="margin: 0 auto;"></div></div></div></div> Of course, create .table and .table-cell css classes